# How do I start editing on a QLineEdit automatically when using a custom itemdelegate for a QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to set up some custom editors for a QTreeview and pretty much have it down but I still have 1 minor problem.

When the user enters a standard editor in the treeview all of the text is automatically selected and any further keystrokes will start editing the data.

I can't seem to figure out how to do that on my custom editors. I though I could just call setFocus, selectAll, and setCursorPosition on the QLineedit in my custom editor from the setEditorData method, but that doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing here?

A working example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class NspStringEdit(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    editingFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NspStringEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(137, 25)
        self.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 25))

        self.Edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.Checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        self.Checkbox.setText("")

        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.Edit)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.Checkbox)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(2, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.Checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self._on_state_change)
        self.Edit.editingFinished.connect(self._on_editingFinished)
        self.Checkbox.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.WheelFocus)

        self.setText(None)

    def _on_state_change(self):
        state = self.checkState()
        if state:
            self.Edit.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.Edit.setEnabled(False)
        self.editingFinished.emit()

    def _on_editingFinished(self):
        self.editingFinished.emit()

    def checkState(self):
        state = self.Checkbox.checkState()
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def setText(self, val):
        self.Edit.setEnabled(True)
        if val is None:
            self.Checkbox.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            self.Edit.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            self.Edit.setText(val)
            self.Checkbox.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)

    def text(self):
        if self.checkState():
            return self.Edit.text()
        else:
            return None


class NspAbstractItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NspAbstractItemDelegate, self).__init__()

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = NspStringEdit(parent)
        editor.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        data = index.data()
        editor.setText(data)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        data = editor.text()
        txt = data
        model.setData(index, txt)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        r = option.rect
        height = r.bottom() - r.top()
        r.setY(r.y() + height)
        if editor.windowFlags() & QtCore.Qt.Popup and editor.parent() is not None:
            r.setTopLeft(editor.parent().mapToGlobal(r.topLeft()))
        editor.setGeometry(r)


class testTreeview(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testTreeview, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mainTree = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.lo = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lo.addWidget(self.mainTree)
        self.setLayout(self.lo)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.mainTree.setModel(self.model)
        self.populate()
        self.mainTree.setItemDelegate(NspAbstractItemDelegate())

    def populate(self):

        row = [QtGui.QStandardItem('05/12/15'), QtGui.QStandardItem('07/13/18'), ]
        row2 = [QtGui.QStandardItem('12/21/21'), QtGui.QStandardItem('11/05/17'), ]
        all_rows = list(row)
        all_rows.extend(row2)
        for item in all_rows:
            item.setEditable(True)
        root = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        root.appendRow(row)
        root.appendRow(row2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    volume = testTreeview()
    volume.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the QLineEdit editor to get the focus and can be edited directly, then you must make QLineEdit the focusProxy of the NspStringEdit:

```
self.Edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
self.setFocusProxy(self.Edit)
```

Comment: This indeed starts editing on the line edit but I lose the ability to tab through columns. Is there a way to maintain that?

Comment: @SeanO You don't point that out in your question. If you have another problem then create another question, that's the logic of SO.

Comment: Alright then, stackoverflow forces me to wait 90 minutes between asking questions. So you will definitely see a followup question today or tomorrow. Can you give me a hint on what I am missing? Unless you need the extra clarification of another post.

Comment: I asked this in a new question if you have any ideas.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203734/how-to-maintain-the-ability-to-tab-through-qtreeview-columns-when-setting-the-fo